# How to update mysql database automatically after every second?

Tags: php, mysql, database, logging

I want to update the 'last_activity' or 'last_seen' value of user in database..
I wrote following code to achieve this:

```
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
$lastseen = $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'];
$lastseen = date("h:i:sa",$lastseen );

$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `lastseen` = '$lastseen' WHERE `username`='$username'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
```

But the problem is that above code will run only one time .I want it to run each and every second so I could get the latest value of 'last seen'.

PS:I have searched a lot on internet but didn't get specific answer .Please help me.

Comment: Activity should be updated when user loads new url, for example. Or do any other action interacting with server. I can open your page and go outside for 6 hours. You will consider me as active? I can open 1K of your pages in my browser and your server will be ddosed.

Comment: you need to load the server script by long ajax polling either use socket.io

Comment: You wouldn't "_want it to run each and every second_" once you reach a certain amount of users, that sound like overkill for your server. Only update `last_seen` when a user performs an action

Comment: Could you people please give the code?

Comment: If the "last_activity" concern only one user : use Ajax to update your content in database + reload the new content without refresh the page so user will see the "last_activity"

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to it - trust me...

but ok

use javascript to make a asynchronous call to a php page where you update the database...
if you use jquery use the built-in function

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/